# Excel VBA loop for if

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to write a vba code in excel with the following condition:

If the difference between 2 cells is less than a number to return that number in a specific cell.

I wrote this:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TD As Date

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
    TD = Now

    i = 1
    Do While Cells(2, 8).Value <> ""
        If (TD - Cells(2, 13).Value) <= i Then
            Cells(2, 8).Value = i
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop    
End Sub
```

But nothing happens

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You only check `Cells(2, 8)` - you do not iterate using `i`

Comment: It is very unclear what you actually want to do. Please give some example data (screenshots might help too) and explain your goal and how the expected result would look like. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.